AMCL is not publishing map -> odom TF [HUMBLE]
I'm working with an ackermann car-like robot. I've just created a map with SLAM and now following the turtlebot3 tutorial I'm loading it in the NAV2 launch with the AMCL. The thing is the map frame is only published when I launch the SLAM_toolbox. My AMCL doesn't publish it. So I cant use my static map.
In theory I know the AMCL publish the map->odom frame but I don't know why when I visualize in RVIZ2, map frame is not available for global frame.
My nav2_params code here:
amcl:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    alpha1: 0.2
    alpha2: 0.2
    alpha3: 0.2
    alpha4: 0.2
    alpha5: 0.2
    base_frame_id: "base_link"
    beam_skip_distance: 0.5
    beam_skip_error_threshold: 0.9
    beam_skip_threshold: 0.3
    do_beamskip: false
    global_frame_id: "map"
    lambda_short: 0.1
    laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
    laser_max_range: 100.0
    laser_min_range: -1.0
    laser_model_type: "likelihood_field"
    max_beams: 60
    max_particles: 2000
    min_particles: 500
    odom_frame_id: "odom"
    pf_err: 0.05
    pf_z: 0.99
    recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
    recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
    resample_interval: 1
    robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::DifferentialMotionModel"
    #robot_model_type: "nav2_amcl::OmniMotionModel"
    save_pose_rate: 0.5
    sigma_hit: 0.2
    tf_broadcast: true
    transform_tolerance: 1.0
    update_min_a: 0.2
    update_min_d: 0.25
    z_hit: 0.5
    z_max: 0.05
    z_rand: 0.5
    z_short: 0.05
    scan_topic: scan

bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odom
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    # 'default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml' and 'default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml' are use defaults:
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_to_pose_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
    # They can be set here or via a RewrittenYaml remap from a parent launch file to Nav2.
    plugin_lib_names:
      - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_smooth_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
      - nav2_assisted_teleop_action_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_bt_node
      - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
      - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_globally_updated_goal_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_is_path_valid_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
      - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
      - nav2_truncate_path_local_action_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
      - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
      - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
      - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
      - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_path_expiring_timer_condition
      - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_updated_controller_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
      - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
      - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
      - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node
      - nav2_controller_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_path_longer_on_approach_bt_node
      - nav2_wait_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_spin_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_back_up_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_assisted_teleop_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_drive_on_heading_cancel_bt_node
      - nav2_is_battery_charging_condition_bt_node

bt_navigator_navigate_through_poses_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    controller_frequency: 20.0
   
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "nav2_mppi_controller::MPPIController"
      time_steps: 56
      model_dt: 0.05
      batch_size: 2000
      vx_std: 0.2
      vy_std: 0.2
      wz_std: 0.4
      vx_max: 0.5
      vx_min: -0.35
      vy_max: 0.5
      wz_max: 1.9
      iteration_count: 1
      prune_distance: 1.7
      transform_tolerance: 0.1
      temperature: 0.3
      gamma: 0.015
      motion_model: "Ackermann"
      visualize: false
      reset_period: 1.0 # (only in Humble)
      regenerate_noises: false
      TrajectoryVisualizer:
        trajectory_step: 5
        time_step: 3
      AckermannConstraints:
        min_turning_r: 0.2
      critics: ["ConstraintCritic", "ObstaclesCritic", "GoalCritic", "GoalAngleCritic", "PathAlignCritic", "PathFollowCritic", "PathAngleCritic", "PreferForwardCritic"]
      ConstraintCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 4.0
      GoalCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0
        threshold_to_consider: 1.4
      GoalAngleCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 3.0
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
      PreferForwardCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
      ObstaclesCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        repulsion_weight: 1.5
        critical_weight: 20.0
        consider_footprint: false
        collision_cost: 10000.0
        collision_margin_distance: 0.1
        near_goal_distance: 0.5
        inflation_radius: 0.55 # (only in Humble)
        cost_scaling_factor: 10.0 # (only in Humble)
      PathAlignCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 14.0
        max_path_occupancy_ratio: 0.05
        trajectory_point_step: 3
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
        offset_from_furthest: 20
        use_path_orientations: false
      PathFollowCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 5.0
        offset_from_furthest: 5
        threshold_to_consider: 1.4
      PathAngleCritic:
        enabled: true
        cost_power: 1
        cost_weight: 2.0
        offset_from_furthest: 4
        threshold_to_consider: 0.5
        max_angle_to_furthest: 1.0
        mode: 0
      # TwirlingCritic:
      #   enabled: true
      #   twirling_cost_power: 1
      #   twirling_cost_weight: 10.0

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      rolling_window: true
      width: 3
      height: 3
      resolution: 0.05
      robot_radius: 0.22
      plugins: ["voxel_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      voxel_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
        enabled: True
        publish_voxel_map: True
        origin_z: 0.0
        z_resolution: 0.05
        z_voxels: 16
        max_obstacle_height: 2.0
        mark_threshold: 0
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      robot_radius: 0.22
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
        inflation_radius: 0.55
      always_send_full_costmap: True

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    # Overridden in launch by the "map" launch configuration or provided default value.
    # To use in yaml, remove the default "map" value in the tb3_simulation_launch.py file & provide full path to map below.
    yaml_filename: "pista.yaml"

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    save_map_timeout: 5.0
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True    #mantiene el mensaje para que si RVIZ se lanza mas tarde poder acceder al mapa.

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    use_sim_time: True
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    GridBased:
      lugin: "nav2_smac_planner/SmacPlannerHybrid"
      downsample_costmap: false           # whether or not to downsample the map
      downsampling_factor: 1              # multiplier for the resolution of the costmap layer (e.g. 2 on a 5cm costmap would be 10cm)
      allow_unknown: true                 # allow traveling in unknown space
      max_iterations: 1000000             # maximum total iterations to search for before failing (in case unreachable), set to -1 to disable
      max_planning_time: 5.0              # max time in s for planner to plan, smooth
      motion_model_for_search: "REEDS_SHEPP"    # Hybrid-A* Dubin, Redds-Shepp
      angle_quantization_bins: 72         # Number of angle bins for search
      analytic_expansion_ratio: 3.5       # The ratio to attempt analytic expansions during search for final approach.
      analytic_expansion_max_length: 3.0  # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: The maximum length of the analytic expansion to be considered valid to prevent unsafe shortcutting
      minimum_turning_radius: 1.0        # minimum turning radius in m of path / vehicle
      reverse_penalty: 50.0                # Penalty to apply if motion is reversing, must be => 1
      change_penalty: 0.0                 # Penalty to apply if motion is changing directions (L to R), must be >= 0
      non_straight_penalty: 1.2           # Penalty to apply if motion is non-straight, must be => 1
      cost_penalty: 3.0                   # Penalty to apply to higher cost areas when adding into the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic. This drives the robot more towards the center of passages. A value between 1.3 - 3.5 is reasonable.
      lookup_table_size: 20.0             # Size of the dubin/reeds-sheep distance window to cache, in meters.
      cache_obstacle_heuristic: false     # Cache the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic between subsiquent replannings of the same goal location. Dramatically speeds up replanning performance (40x) if costmap is largely static.
      smooth_path: False # was True                   # If true, does a simple and quick smoothing post-processing to the path

smoother_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    smoother_plugins: ["simple_smoother"]
    simple_smoother:
      plugin: "nav2_smoother::SimpleSmoother"
      tolerance: 1.0e-10
      max_its: 1000
      do_refinement: True

behavior_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    behavior_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "drive_on_heading", "assisted_teleop", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/BackUp"
    drive_on_heading:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/DriveOnHeading"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Wait"
    assisted_teleop:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/AssistedTeleop"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_tolerance: 0.1
    use_sim_time: true
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True

waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    loop_rate: 20
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200

velocity_smoother:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    smoothing_frequency: 20.0
    scale_velocities: False
    feedback: "OPEN_LOOP"
    max_velocity: [0.26, 0.0, 1.0]
    min_velocity: [-0.26, 0.0, -1.0]
    max_accel: [2.5, 0.0, 3.2]
    max_decel: [-2.5, 0.0, -3.2]
    odom_topic: "odom"
    odom_duration: 0.1
    deadband_velocity: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    velocity_timeout: 1.0

In my spawn launch I have the localization node. The launch for nav2 is from nav2_bringup package and the bringup_launch.py there I load my map.
This is the error I see on terminal:
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1714413725.367445883] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available, tf error: Invalid frame ID "map" passed to canTransform argument target_frame - frame does not exist
Any idea where could be the issue?
Thank you very much!

Is it possible give the complete terminal output? Could it be possible that you have to give a initial pose of the robot. Normally you can do this in rviz. You can also do it with a topic.

Hi Nobel, this is the beginning of the terminal loop: *[lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Activating planner_server
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1714413712.367228787] [planner_server]: Activating
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1714413712.367318082] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Activating
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1714413712.367347127] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Checking transform
[component_container_isolated-1] [INFO] [1714413712.367382009] After this start the message I put in my post in a loop

Please provide your full logs

I have found where was the issue. I didn`t give the initial pose because I thought the problem came from another thing because the termial, after I launched the robot and the nav2 bring_up, was full of messages saying they map is not received.
So if you are in the same situation no matter the terminal say, give the initial pose and then see if the simulation works.
Thank you to everyone!!

Close the question by accepting your own answer.
